# Google Scripts and Gmail: Problem with adding a label

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

Can somebody tell me why the following script is not adding the label "Processed"? 
It is giving me an error of "TypeError: Cannot call method "addToThread" of null. (line 18, file "Code")"

Thank you

```
 function FetchYesterdayReport() {

  var filter = "newer_than:1d from:tomas@wasteless.com subject:TestReport "
  var threads = GmailApp.search(filter);
  var message = threads[0].getMessages()[0];
  var attachment = message.getAttachments()[0];

  // Is the attachment a CSV file
  if (attachment.getContentType() === "text/csv") {

    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1kyiyc4wB6yZVeO_Wcs2yeUk_pb-BsE2LcDL50c0oJLY");
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("DATA");
    var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(attachment.getDataAsString(), "|");   
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);

    // Label message as Processed
    var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Processed");
    label.addToThread(threads[0]);
    //Remove from Inbox
    message.markRead();
    threads[0].moveToArchive();
  }

}
```

Comment: When the label name is existing, `GmailLabel` is returned from `GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(labelName)`. The error message means that `Processed` is not existing as the label. So can you confirm whether the label is existing and the label name is correct?

Comment: Indeed, I have previously created the label "Processed".

Comment: Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize that my comment was not useful. But I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Done, now its working. The problem was that it was a label Nested over another label, and that is not recognized by the script.
Thank you!